# PHP MySQL insert query using $_POST variables not working

Tags: php, mysqli, insert

I am trying to insert variables into a table in my database, and for some reason, the INSERT query is not inserting my values into said database. I've tested the "test_input" function, which worked fine, and I know the connection is working since a SELECT query I have later on in the code is working. I also know the inputs are in the $_POST superglobal, so I thought it probably had to do with the insert query by way of ruling out the other possibilities. Is there anything wrong with the query? Here is my php code:

```
            function test_input($data) {
            $data = trim($data);
            $data = stripslashes($data);
            $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
            return $data;
        }

        $name = test_input($_POST['name']);
        $date = test_input($_POST['date']);
        $datestring = date('Y-m-d',strtotime(test_input($_POST['date'])));
        $venue = test_input($_POST['venue']);
        $town = test_input($_POST['town']);

        $connection = new mysqli("Example","Example","Example","Example");
        if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
            echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
        }   

        if($_POST != []) {
            $connection->query("INSERT INTO events (Name, Date, Venue, Town) VALUES(" . $name . ", " . $datestring . ", " . $venue . ", " . $town . ")");
        }
```

Here is my HTML form code if anything is wrong with that.

```
    <div class="tr" id="addevent">      

        <form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">

        <div class="td">
        <input type="text" name="name">
        </div>

        <div class="td">
        <input type="text" name="date">
        </div>      

        <div class="td">
        <input type="text" name="venue">
        </div>          

        <div class="td">
        <input type="text" name="town">
        </div>  

        <div class="td">
        <input type="submit" value="Add Event">
        </div>

        </form>

    </div>
```

Comment: You probably want to check your condition `$_POST != []`. Maybe you can test `isset($_POST['name'])` instead. Or any other form parameter that must exist. Try echo in the if statement and see if it is executed at all.

Comment: Please remove `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` as your action. I know you have `htmlspecialchars()` but either one of those is like a hackers heaven. See here for more info - https://phpsecurity.wordpress.com/2007/11/03/the-danger-of-php_self/ and here for why htmlspecialchars is a problem in itself - http://blog.astrumfutura.com/2012/03/a-hitchhikers-guide-to-cross-site-scripting-xss-in-php-part-1-how-not-to-use-htmlspecialchars-for-output-escaping/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not working because the dynamic SQL insert statement you are creating will have unquoted strings in the `VALUES` list and therefore be malformed. Having said that, you really shouldn't be doing it this way at all, as it's vulnerable to a very common attack called [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).